# NHibernate session management in NServiceBus with Autofac

Tags: nhibernate, nservicebus, autofac

Andreas Ohlund has an excellent article [here](http://andreasohlund.blogspot.com/2010/02/nhibernate-session-management-in.html) on how to use Structuremap to wire the NHibernate session so that it enlists in the NSB transaction automatically.

Does anyone know if it is possible to achieve the same with Autofac?

Answer (score 1):

I have been given the awnser by a colleague

```
public class NHibernateMessageModule : IMessageModule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Injected SessionManager.
    /// </summary>
    public ISessionManager SessionManager { get; set; }

    public void HandleBeginMessage()
    {
        //this session need for NServiceBus and for us
        ThreadStaticSessionContext.Bind(SessionManager.OpenSession()); //CurrentSessionContext or  ThreadStaticSessionContext
    }

    public void HandleEndMessage()
    {
        SessionManager.Session.Flush();
    }

    public void HandleError()
    {
    }
}
```

public interface ISessionManager 
    {
        ISession Session { get; }
        ISession OpenSession();
        bool IsSessionOpened { get; }
        void CloseSession();
    }

public class NHibernateSessionManager : ISessionManager
    {
        private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
        private ISession _session;

```
    public ISession Session
    {
        get { return _session; } 
        private set { _session = value; }
    }

    public SchemaExport SchemaExport { get; set; }


    public NHibernateSessionManager(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public bool IsSessionOpened
    {
        get { return Session != null && Session.IsOpen; } 
    }

    public ISession OpenSession()
    {
        if(Session == null)
        {
            Session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
            if (SchemaExport != null)
                SchemaExport.Execute(true, true, false, Session.Connection, null);
        }
        return Session;
    }

    public void CloseSession()
    {
        if (Session != null && Session.IsOpen)
        {
            Session.Flush();
            Session.Close();
        }
        Session = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: wont these introduce weird kinda locks in your system?

Answer (score 1):

You do exactly the same as in the articke you mention but select one of the Autofac lifescopes. If you have other classes involved in message handling where you want your session to be injected, you use InstancePerLifetimeScope like this

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Publisher, IWantCustomInitialization
{

    public void Init()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Register(s => SessionFactory.CreateSessionFactory()).As<ISessionFactory>().SingleInstance();
        builder.Register(x => x.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).As<ISession>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        var container = builder.Build();
        Configure.With().AutofacBuilder(container);
    }

}
```

You can also register any other dependencies you need within your NSB context and you will be sure it is instantiated and dosposed properly due to the use of child container.